# how do I change the background of tableView without interface builder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, tableview

I'm trying to learn how to program without using Interface builder, and i have stumbled upon a problem, how do i change the background from the default UITableViewStyleGrouped to a background of my own, and then the same applies for the cells, how do i change them without using interface builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an image pattern:

```
myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Or use the UITableView backgroundView attribute:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `backgroundColor` and `backgroundView` of either `UITableView` or  `UITableViewCell`.

Comment: okay i tried the follow:    tableView.backgroundView = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundimage.png"];   and it doesn't work, what am i missing?

Comment: UIImage is not a UIView !! Use UIImageView!

Answer (score 1):

To change the background of the table styled as UITableViewStyleGrouped just use:

```
myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

and if you want to change the color of a cell, you can do the following on cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

Comment: what about if i wanted to use an image instead of a color?